# AVERAGEIFS values that are not NA

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have the following `AVERAGEIFS` that averages column I grouped by the values in column B

```
= AVERAGEIFS(B:B, A:A, A:A)
```

Problem is, sometimes, the column B sometimes contains an `NA()` error.  How do I filter these out of the equation?

I tried to do a filter

```
= AVERAGEIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(B:B),B:B)), A:A,A:A)
```

but this gives me an error.

Here is some sample data:

```
* A    *  B  *
| Fred |  8  |
| Bill |  9  |
| Jane |  NA |
| Jane |  9  |
| Fred |  NA |
| Bill |  5  |
| Fran |  9  |
| Fred |  4  |
| Jane |  1  |
```

What I want is to add a column C which shows next to each row, the person's average not counting the NAs.

```
* A    *  B  * C *
| Fred |  8  | 6 |
| Bill |  9  | 7 |
| Jane |  NA |   |
| Jane |  9  | 5 |
| Fred |  NA |   |
| Bill |  5  | 7 |
| Fran |  9  | 9 |
| Fred |  4  | 6 |
| Jane |  1  | 5 |
```

As for the blank spots, I don't care much for what happens there - it can be an error, or a blank, so long as the `NA`s don't affect the average I don't care.

Comment: Could you perhaps include some sample data for us to look at?

Comment: @Burgi edited in an example

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - IFNA() with Array**

I don't really understand what your `AVERAGEIFS` is actually supposed to be doing, but all you need to do to fix this is to use the `IFNA()` along with an array formula (`Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when entering the formula):

`= AVERAGEIFS(IFNA(B:B,""), A:A, A:A)`

This turns `NA()` values into blanks in the data you're handling.

---

**Option 2 - Clean your Data**

This would normally be my option 1, but I'm aware it's not what you've asked for, and so I've demoted it to 2...

Obviously, all the above formula does is replace `NA()` with blank values. Alternatively, why not just initially have your cells calculating as blanks? This will make your columns look nicer too.

Whatever calculation you have in your base cells, either change the `NA()` option to return `""` instead, or wrap the whole calculation in `IFNA([insert calculation here],"")`

Answer (score -1):

A not so smart way will be adding a new hidden column (say column D) with:

> =IF(ISNUMBER(B:B),B:B,0)

Then your `=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,A:A,A:A)` will work as intended:

```
Fred    8   4
Bill    9   7
Jane    NA  3.333333333
Jane    9   3.333333333
Fred    NA  4
Bill    5   7
Fran    9   9
Fred    4   4
Jane    1   3.333333333
```

Comment: This will do precisely what I *don't* want it to do - note jane's average in your example is 3.3 even though `(9+1)/2 = 5`. If you assume all NAs are 0s that breaks the entire concept of an average. If I was ok with that I would just use a nested IF and be done with it.